# unity convert a float to a vector3 c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

Here is my error message:

> Assets/BanditLogic.cs(45,30): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert
>   type 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'

And here is a section of the code:

```
Vector3 Distance = Vector3.Distance (player.transform.position,bandit.transform.position);
anim.SetFloat ("DistanceToPlayer", Distance);
```

I'm trying to find the distance to the enemy from the player, if there are any easier ways please let me know.

Comment: if oxrock's answer fixed your issue, please accept it as your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on the right track. You assigned your variable to a vector3 instead of a float.

```
float Distance = Vector3.Distance (player.transform.position,bandit.transform.position); 
anim.SetFloat ("DistanceToPlayer", Distance);
```

this should work

Comment: Really minor point, but I'd put a line break between your first and second lines of code for readability!

Comment: I agree, I just quickly copy pasted but I cleaned it up a tad upon your request for posterity.